# Creating dropdown menu with submenus appearing on rollover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am looking to create CSS that will display these links below in "left to right" divs and when action like "rollover" happens the appropriate sub-menu's will appear right below the menu they just rolled over.

Here is the KEY. This menu will be "Dynamically Loaded" from wordpress database so I need to know how to style the "main menus" and then on the rollover of each menu the dropdown will appear below in the right spot. But I can't hard coded names as the menu items will change etc.. does this make sense?

Here is one dynamic example loaded from a a wordpress database.

THIS CODE BELOW:

```
<? 
require('wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<div class="access">
  <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</div>
```

LOADS THE FOLLOWING HTML BELOW:

```
<div class="access">
  <div class="menu-papamenu-container"><ul id="menu-papamenu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45"><a href="?p=love">Home</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-46"><a href="?p=Happy">Happy</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47"><a href="?p=coolBeans">Cool Beans</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-49"><a href="?p=SoHappy">So Happy</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-48"><a href="?p=Contact">Contact Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-50"><a href="?p=Address">Address</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a href="?p=Phone">Phone</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-52"><a href="?p=Email">Email</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53"><a href="?p=About">About Us</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-54"><a href="?p=Company">Company</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-55"><a href="?p=CompanyAddress">Company Address</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div></div>
```

**But how can I add CSS to give it the proper navigation drop downs etc**?

The OUTPUT without CSS can be [seen here](http://timstaples.com/testingMenu.php).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to make the top level li's `inline-block`s for this and then make the sub-menus `block`s. Then just use of the css :hover selector and some absolute positioning of the sub-menus does the job. Made a fiddle for you to demonstrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredkhan/EuH8P/1

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you soo much. You both got it right on! Amazing. Only problem is I don't know who to give the right answer to because for both of you it says 5 hours. Who answered first I guess should get it? Nevertheless I thank you both from the bottom of my heart. :)

Comment: Both are valid solutions, take your pick! Just be aware that Steven's solution will affect content below it so if you put content under the menu div it will be pushed down when a submenu is opened. Mine avoids that because of the use of absolute positioning. It really depends what you're going for.

Comment: Hey Jared I have a question for you. Can I email you? Or can we start a private chat? I think we have to chat a lot before we have that option. Well at least ten more responses.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/UVkGG/

```
.menu{
    white-space:nowrap; /* Stops the menu from wrapping if the container is too small */
}
.menu>li{
    display:inline-block; /* Put menu items on one line */
    height:20px; /* Set default height for top level menu */
    width:200px;
    padding:5px;
    line-height:24px;
    background:#eee;
    vertical-align:top; /* Align menu li's to top of page*/
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:hidden; /* Hide sub menu */
}
.menu>li:hover{
    height:auto; /* Remove height limit to show sub menu */
}
.sub-menu{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.sub-menu>li{
    display:block; /* Put sub-menu items on separate lines */
    padding:5px;
    margin:2px;
    background:#ccc;
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.sub-menu>li:hover{
    background:#aaa;
}
.menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#111;
    font-weight:bold; 
    display:block; /* Makes the entire highlighted block clickable not just the text */
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you soo much. You both got it right on! Amazing. Only problem is I don't know who to give the right answer to because for both of you it says 5 hours. Who answered first I guess should get it? Nevertheless I thank you both from the bottom of my heart. :)